Change coordinate format from Decimal to Degree Minute Second in the Printlayout-Mode QGIS
Hello I am a beginner in QGIS. During my last project I came across the following issue: I have created a Printmap in the Layout menu which is designed in EPSG:32631 obviously the coordinates are shown in decimal format.

Is there any possibility I have, to change die format for the print layout in the Degree Minute Second format? During my research regarding the issue I didn't find any functional solution. If someone has an idea I would be glad to hear from you!

Yes, change the grid crs to wgs84 or 4326 and select DMS as the format
